# Probability of choosing correctly many times the answer.

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a questionary of $5$ questions, each one has $4$ answers. I wanted to calculate what is the probability of choosing the correct answers five times. It seems very easy:

$$P_5(5) = \binom{5}{5}(0.25)^5 = \frac{1}{256}$$

However, a common thought of some people is that if you answer **(a)** in all the questions (from the options a, b, c and d) it seems to have more probability of success in at least one answer, as there is a big probability of having one correct answer that is **a**.

I mean that there is more probability to answer in the five questions **a**, **a**, **a**, **a** ,**a**; instead of e.g. **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**. This is because if you answer as the first example, there is a big probability that there will be at least one **a** as correct answer. However, if you do as the second example, there is a bigger probability that you didn't answer in a correct order.

---

Do I have a misunderstanding?

If you have five questions with $4$ answers each (but only one correct), which is the best order to answer according to mathematics?

I hope I'm clear.

Comment: If you have four possible answers to each question, then presumably **e** is not an option.  As to your assumption, that depends on whether the examiner chooses the order of answers at random, or spreads them out [to look random](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/why-random-shuffle-feels-far-from-random-10066621.html)

Comment: @Henry thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation assumes that the correct answers are selected uniformly and randomly from the choices.  If you know something about the psychology of the test maker, you may be able to do better.  Maybe the test maker is unwilling to have the correct answer always be the same, for example.  On the other hand, quizzes in magazines often have the correct answer always the same so that scoring is easy. If you know some of the answers, you can guess the rest with high assurance.  This is not mathematics, however.

Answer (score 1):

If you know nothing about the questions or the answers, then each series of answers is equally likely to have them all (or have any) correct. It is true that it's likely that there is at least one answer $a$, and thus the sequence of answers $(a,a,a,a,a)$ is likely to have at least one correct.

However, it is equally likely that the first or fifth answers will be $a$ or the second answer will be $b$ or the third will be $c$ or the fourth will be $d$, so the sequence of $(a,b,c,d,a)$ is equally likely to have at least one correct.

In real situations, choosing $(a,a,a,a,a)$ is probably a bad choice; if your teacher randomly chose the places for the correct answers, and out came $(a,a,a,a,a)$ they probably reordered the answers.

Comment: if any answers are numerical, and are listed in numerical order, then there is a theory that some mistakes will make an answer too small and others make it too large, therefore a and e could be less likely for numerical answers, with c hypothesised to be the most likely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the tiny probability of getting *all 5* answers correct, as opposed to maximizing your expected score on the quiz, make sure your guesses agree with anything you know or expect about the sequence of correct answers. Under various assumptions, **a,a,a,a,a** has zero chance of matching all the correct answers, so some guess sequences are better than others. On the other hand, as long as the isolated probability that **x** is the answer to any specific question remains $0.25$ for each **x**, even under the assumptions, there is no strategy that can maximize the *expected* number of correct guesses, because of the linearity of expectation.